# How to calculate the trace and the determinant of a matrix given an annihilating polynomial?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

> Find the trace and determinant of the $5 \times 5$ matrix $A$ that satisfies the condition $$ \sum_{k=0}^{5} (k+1)A^k = 0 $$

---

My attempt relies on the fact that the given condition can be thought as its Cayley-Hamilton polynomial, since it can be written exactly as $P_5(A) = 0$. Considering this fact, I can also say that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $P_5(\lambda) = 0$. As check for my attempt, I tried to compute the roots of that polynomial with WolframAlpha, and discovered that the "sum of roots = $-\frac{5}{6}$" and "product of roots = $-\frac{1}{6}$". Those results are indeed the trace and determinant of $A$, as the book give me also the solution, but since I'm not able to find easily these roots (I was't able to find them at all!), I think that my attempt is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the sum correctly? What you wrote is equivalent to $A^5=0$.

Comment: @HappyDay you're right, I wrote wrong, the edit of ParclyTaxel is the correct one.. do you refer to this?

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas
The sum of the roots is: -(coefficient of A^4)/(coefficient of A^5)=-5/6

Comment: Wow that formula is a great tool! However.. can you review my attempt? I mean, beyond the brute search of all roots of the polynomial, is my reasonement for characteristic polynomial correct?

Comment: @giuliolib What makes you think you can find the roots of a quintic polynomial?

Comment: Unless your book has other constraints imposed on $A$, the trace/determinant need not be $-\frac56$ and $-\frac16$. This is because if $\lambda$ is any root of $P_5(\lambda) = 0$, then $A = \lambda I$ also satisfy $P_5(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit more work to implement what you want. The fact that a polynomial of degree $5$ is zero on a $5\times5$ matrix is not enough to tell that it is the characteristic polynomial. For a simple example consider the $5\times5$ matrix $E_{11}$ (this is the matrix with $1$ at the $1,1$ entry and zero elsewhere). The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $x^4(x-1)$. But since the minimal polynomial is $x(x-1)$, the polynomials $x^3(x-1)^2$,  $x^2(x-1)^3$, and $x(x-1)^4$ are also degree-five polynomials that annihilate $E_{11}$.

What works in this example to guarantee that your $P_5$ is indeed the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is that $P_5$ has five distinct roots. As mentioned by Macavity in the comments, one can do this by showing that the greatest common divisor between $P_5$ and $P_5'$ is $1$; that would show that $P_5$ has no common roots with its derivative, and thus guarantee that all roots are simple. When the five roots are distinct, you know that $P_5$ is the minimal polynomial, and being of degree $5$ it has to be the characteristic polynomial.

As for how to answer the question, over $\mathbb C$ the (monic version of) the characteristic polynomial is
$$
(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)(x-\lambda_4)(x-\lambda_5).
$$
The independent term of this polynomial is $$(-1)^5\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4\lambda_5=-\det A.$$ And the coefficient of $x^4$ is
$$
-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4+\lambda_5)=-\operatorname{Tr}(A).
$$
So, since the monic characteristici polynomial of $A$ is
$$
x^5 + \frac56x^4 + \frac46x^3 + \frac12x^2 + \frac13x + \frac16,
$$
it follows that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A)=-\frac56,\qquad\qquad\det A=-\frac16.
$$

Comment: Well one could always find  $\gcd(P_5, P_5')$ to check for multiple roots, say using the Euclidean algorithm...  +1 for bringing up the point though.

Comment: Good point, I should have noticed that but my algebra is fairly rusty.

Comment: Thus, I have some questions about these statements: 1) If the roots of any polynomial are all and only the eigenvalues of the matrix (with the correct multeplicity), I know for sure that is the characteristic polynomial (follows directly from the definition); 2) Special case: if all the roots of any "correct-degree" polynomial are distinct, then I know for sure that is the characteristic polynomial (how can I state that the roots are necessarly the eigenvalues?)

Comment: For example, in my specific case, how would I had say that $P_5(\lambda)$ have five distinct roots?

Comment: 1) Yes, that can be taken as the definition of the characteristic polynomial (usually, together with "monic" so that you have uniqueness). 2) Yes, but it depends on what "correct degree" means. The key facts are that the minimal polynomial divides any polynomial that is zero on the matrix, and that the roots of the minimal polynomial are simple and they are precisely the eigenvalues. Any polynomial $q$ with $q(A)=0$ will have the eigenvalues of $A$ as roots. Your particular $P_5$ has simple roots, so it has to be the minimal polynomial (the only way to reduce degree is to erase roots)

Comment: The reason it has to be the minimal (and characteristic, in this case) polynomial is that it is  of degree $5$ and divides the characteristic polynomial which is also of degree $5$.

Comment: As for how to say that it has distinct roots, either you find them somehow, or you show that it is coprime with its derivative.

Comment: Ok, I finally good with the concept itself.. but the practice remains difficult: in my example, I can't easily demonstrate that the polynomial is coprime with its derivative.. how can you show this?

Comment: It's not fun, but it is not too hard to do the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was searching for an easy escape, but this way still seems to me as 'not much efficient/general'.. I mean let's suppose that the example asks for an $n \times n$ matrix with condition: $\sum_{k=0}^{5} (k+1)A^k = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.. or maybe with $n=2023$ (you know, those tricky tests). In those situations Euclidean algorithm still hold?

Comment: If it is a tricky test, there will be some smart way of finding out. If it is a natural question instead, writing software to perform the Euclidean algorithm is not hard (like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=18ca12c754852a11ca8ffbbeeee77b76)).

Comment: Ok, that's definitely a time-eater way to be doable in an exam, but I've convinced myself that this way is covering pretty general cases. Thank you for your time and dedication <3